# How to use insert in the set in c++ for user defined data type?

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, set

I would like to use a `set<vector<data>>` where `data` is a user-defined class and both the `set` and the `vector` are *STL*,

```
class  data  
{  
    int info;  
};
```

I am not able to understand whether we need to define *comparator* operator for both `vector<data>` and `data` class or only `data` class.
And how do we define the *comparator* operator for the same?

Comment: Do you really want a set of vector of data? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: A set needs to know if two elements are the same, as it will not store duplicates (because they are the same thing).   So you must provide a way to tell if two vectors are the same, which isn't something one would commonly do with a vector.   This screams of you not doing the right thing.

Comment: There's a smell of XY problem here

Comment: If the default ordering of `std::vector` isn't suitable, you need to define your own. You always need to define an ordering for your own classes.

Comment: If you can define when two vectors are/should be considered duplicate, then only I think set of vector would make sense. Any practical example you can think of that?

Comment: Example using it to do UNION operation between any two tables then set would eliminate duplicate rows.

Comment: yes I really want a set of vector of data , because checking/removing duplicates would be easier and better time complexity with set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::vector` already has an ordering - lexicographical order - so you normally don't need to do anything with that.

You always need to define an ordering for your own classes if you use the default vector ordering (see example below for a case where you don't need to), and the most common way is to overload `operator<`.

Note that the ordering relation must be a [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings), or using the set is undefined.

If you want a special sense of "equality" for the set, you need to define your own.

For example, this code would make a set where vectors of equal length are considered equal (so only the first one encountered of each length is added to the set):

```
template<typename T>
struct shorter_vector
{
    bool operator() (const std::vector<T>& left, const std::vector<T>& right) const
    {
        return left.size() < right.size();
    }

};

// ...
struct A { int x; };
std::set<std::vector<A>, shorter_vector<A>> samelengths;
samelengths.insert({A{1}});
samelengths.insert({A{2}});
samelengths.insert({A{3},A{4}});
samelengths.insert({A{5},A{67}});
// set now contains {A{1}} and {A{3},A{4}}
```

Note that this set doesn't need an ordering for the vector's elements, since the equivalence relation is defined on structure alone.